# vue toggle class for dropdown menu

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i want to toggle **active-submenu** class to **li** tag when am click on **a** link to show dropdown menu using VueJS but i don't know how please help me

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <li class="active-submenu">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="uil-envelope-alt"></i>
        <span>Email</span>
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="email-inbox">Inbox</a>
          <a href="email-inbox-read">Email Read</a>
          <a href="email-compose">Email Compose</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="uil-shopping-basket"></i>
        <span>E-commerce</span>
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="shop-card">Products Grid</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="shop-listing">Products List</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="shop-product">Product</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

Comment: You should assign a `@click` handler for A tags which will set the `currentPage` variable - then you can use `<li :class="{'active-submenu': currentPage ===1}">`

Comment: how sorry i am new with vue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <li :class="{'active-submenu': activeEmail}">
      <a href="#" @click.prevent="activeEmail = !activeEmail">
        <i class="uil-envelope-alt"></i>
        <span>Email</span>
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="email-inbox">Inbox</a>
          <a href="email-inbox-read">Email Read</a>
          <a href="email-compose">Email Compose</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li :class="{'active-submenu': activeCommerce}">
      <a href="#" @click.prevent="activeCommerce = !activeCommerce">
        <i class="uil-shopping-basket"></i>
        <span>E-commerce</span>
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="shop-card">Products Grid</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="shop-listing">Products List</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="shop-product">Product</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default
{
  name: 'MyCustomMenu',
  data()
  {
    return {
      activeEmail: true,
      activeCommerce: false,
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: it's not toggle click it's a just a click and then it's add the class but after i have click again it's not remove the class

Comment: before i use this

Comment: methods: {
    setActive() {
      this.active = !this.active;
      this.active
        ? event.target.parentElement.classList.add('active-submenu')
        : event.target.parentElement.classList.remove('active-submenu');
    },

Comment: but when am click on it again it's scoll the page to the top

Comment: Ok, I have updated the code to work with "toggling" rather than "switching"